# Поиск числа после определенного символа, почему только одно совпадение?

Tags: php

```
$inputString = '->11гe+20∆∆A+4µcњil->5•Ћ®†Ѓ p+5f-7Ќ¬f pro+10g+1悦ra->58->44m+1*m+2a喜er!';

preg_match("/->(\d+)/",$inputString,$output);

print($output[1]);
```

в $output[1] попадает число 11, в $output[2] пусто, почему? Как получить все числа после определенного символа?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию `preg_match_all`

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php

```
    $inputString = '->11гe+20∆∆A+4µcњil->5•Ћ®†Ѓ p+5f-7Ќ¬f pro+10g+1悦ra->58->44m+1*m+2a喜er!';

    preg_match_all("/->(\d+)/", $inputString, $output);

    print_r($output);
```